# What's the best training for a reactive dog?

Tags: training

I live in the city and my dog, 11 month corgi, is so reactive to every person or animal we pass. Walks take far too long since he wants to stop for everything - including playing with every dog we pass, or refusing to walk if distracted by a noise or passerby.
Does anyone have advice on the best training for helping him be less reactive? I've done training with treats, but as soon as the treat is gone he's back to his usual behavior.

Comment: Can you explain his behavior a little more? What exactly does he do when he "wants to stop for everything"? Does he want to attack, hide away, play with dogs, refuse to walk? Please [edit] your question to add more details.